# Scrapy: 1) What is throttling the spider 2) How to delete aged request objects?

Tags: python, scrapy

I understand this is inherently a difficult question to answer without knowing what the full code is.

Here is a summary of the code:

- Starts with lots of start-urls
- Saves some data to the metadata
- Has a global dictionary variable, initiated with current time
- Follows all links that share the same domain
- Checks current time with initiation time and does not follow when the difference is too high. Some domains have too many links ([How to limit scrapy request objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27943970/how-to-limit-scrapy-request-objects))

But generally, what causes such a non smooth curve for requests? I don’t have much processing so I would have thought they will basically make as many requests as is allowed under concurrent requests. Furthermore I have set concurrent requests to 256 and request per IP = 1 so it shouldn’t be because of any specific website. The other interesting thing is it starts off fast and slows down. That I can understand as the slow requests stay in the system longer, and drag down the average.

Any thoughts would be welcome.

[image]

```
[scrapy.crawler] Overridden settings: {'AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED': True, 'BOT_NAME': 'stack', 'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS': 256, 'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN': 1, 'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_IP': 1, 'DEPTH_LIMIT': 3, 'DEPTH_PRIORITY': 1, 'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 1, 'LOG_ENABLED': False, 'LOG_LEVEL': 'INFO', 'MEMUSAGE_LIMIT_MB': 950, 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'stack.spiders', 'REACTOR_THREADPOOL_MAXSIZE': 30, 'SCHEDULER_DISK_QUEUE': 'scrapy.squeues.PickleFifoDiskQueue', 'SCHEDULER_MEMORY_QUEUE': 'scrapy.squeues.FifoMemoryQueue', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['stack.spiders'], 'STATS_CLASS': 'sh_scrapy.stats.HubStorageStatsCollector', 'TELNETCONSOLE_HOST': '0.0.0.0',}
```

**Update**
I tried setting the concurrent request to inf, and that resolved the linearity issue but created a secondary problem. 
[image]

Based on this update is it more obvious what is throttling the spider?

However, now the scheduled requests are higher than the actual requests by about 20%, resulting in memory usage to grow as the program continues. Is there a way to delete aged request objects so that memory usage does not grow over time?

Comment: Maybe the websites are throttling you?

Comment: It could be, but I would think given the diversity of websites (concurrent ip=1 and concurrent requests =256 that wouldn’t be the case). To be clear I’m doing a broad crawl. Any reason why a broad crawl would have all these requests end up on one website? I can understand that if scrapy is limiting it to 1 request per ip, and all 256 requests are for that one IP, then it would slow down.

Comment: I’ve set DEPTH_PRIORITY = 1
SCHEDULER_DISK_QUEUE = 'scrapy.squeues.PickleFifoDiskQueue'
SCHEDULER_MEMORY_QUEUE = 'scrapy.squeues.FifoMemoryQueue'

Comment: I have a similar assumption as @L3viathan. First of all, `CONCURRENT_REQUEST=256` is a crazy amount. And this is normal that the website throttles your bot. Now, that's right in the [documentation of Scrapy](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#concurrent-requests-per-ip) to set `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_IP` does not take over `CONCURRENT_REQUEST`. I don't know how you wrote your code to launch a spider through different IPs but I suggest that actually your bot settings applie `CONCURRENT_REQUEST=256` above all, and does not consider `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_IP=1`.

Comment: "I suggest that actually your bot settings applied CONCURRENT_REQUEST=256 above all and does not consider CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_IP=1" any idea on how to do this?

Comment: I'm going to try adding these, and see if they help SCHEDULER_PRIORITY_QUEUE = 'scrapy.pqueues.DownloaderAwarePriorityQueue'; 
REDIRECT_ENABLED = False;

Comment: If your question is "how to make the settings consider `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_IP=1` above all ?" I am sorry because I have no answer to give you because this is not the strategy I apply on my crawler. I apply a reasonable `CONCURRENT_REQUEST=32` in settings file and prefer to launch several instances of a spider with different IPs as I told [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57849706/10314460) to a stack user. Besides if you only have one IP this is paradoxical to set `CONCURRENT_REQUEST=256` and asking `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_IP=1` in the same time in one spider instance,idk how you set it

Comment: If you call `dir()` in your runtime, you'll find all the existing request objects.  From there you can call `del` on whichever ones you like